# How can I update certificates on my system to fix wget's error: "Unable to establish SSL connection."?

Tags: wget, curl, ssl, https, certificates

Sometimes I notice that I am unable to connect via SSL with `curl` and `wget` to websites that have certificates that should be valid.

One example might be `https://squareup.com/` which has a Verisign class 3 certificate - I assume a large banking-related site has a certificate that should be widely accepted.

However when I try and run:

```
wget -O - https://squareup.com/   #grab the homepage and send it to stdout
```

I get the error:

```
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Does this mean my system's certs, perhaps one of the `cacert.pem` files, is out of date?

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.1.

Yes, I know I can use `no-check-certificate` but I'm more curious about why this is happening in the first place.

How can I update certificates on my system to fix wget's error: "Unable to establish SSL connection."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `certutil` to install a certificate.

[Some](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/confusa/wiki/Managing_certificates_with_Google_Chrome) [examples](http://blog.avirtualhome.com/adding-ssl-certificates-to-google-chrome-linux-ubuntu/) that used to work back when Chrome did not support installation of certificates from the UI.

[More usage examples](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Directory_Server/8.1/html/Administration_Guide/Managing_SSL-Using_certutil.html) and a [detailed description](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/tools/certutil.html)

Comment: looks right although i can't get it to work.